# Unable to create new group inside Administrative Unit using Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I intend to create a new group inside an Administrative Unit in AAD programmatically. I will run this under the context of a service principal.

I am facing 2 issues:

1. Unable to find AddAsync() on Graph SDK version 4.52.0

   `await graphClient.Directory.AdministrativeUnits["{administrativeUnit-id}"].Members.Request().AddAsync(newGroupObject);`

Error - [image: AddAsync missing error]

2. GroupAdministrato role on AU:

I assigned GroupAdministrator role to my service principal + `Directory.Read.All` graph API permission, however, I am still not able to create a new group inside AU and it says insufficient privileges.

Endpoint - `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/administrativeUnits/40335129-6bd0-4190-a383-a42e3eae09dc/members/`

If I assign `AdministrativeUnit.ReadWrite.All` permission to service principal, I am able to create the group inside AU.

Why is Group Administrator role not working as intended? Am I missing something?

For issue # 2, If I assign `AdministrativeUnit.ReadWrite.All` permission to service principal, I am able to create the group inside AU.

Comment: You are now using ms graph API, that means when you give enough API permission to the Azure AD application (I mean the permissions listed below), then users in your tenant can use your application to add group to admin unit, no matter the user principle has an admin role or not.

Comment: Do you have any update?

Answer (score 1):

Issue one, let's the [API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/administrativeunit-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request), it should be code below to add group.

```
await graphClient.Directory.AdministrativeUnits["{administrativeUnit-id}"].Members.References
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(directoryObject);
```

For Issue 2, let see the API permission section, you need `group ReadWrite` permission and `Directory ReadWrite` permission to add group to Administrative Units. That's why you get `insufficient privileges` error with `Directory.Read.All`. You only have `Read permission`.

[image]

Then you mentioned you add `GroupAdministrator role` to your service principal. It only allow to create Group, but not add group to Administrative Units.

[image]

Comment: For Issue 1, your solution is to add an EXISTING group to AU. I want to directly create a new group inside AU. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/administrativeunit-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-create-a-new-group

Comment: For issue 2, granting Group.ReadWrite.All permission kills the entire purpose of AU. That is why they came up with Group Administrator role. If I have  Group.ReadWrite.All on entire tenant, why may I need Group Administrator role? 

Wondering if Group Administrator role is working as intended.

Comment: For issue one, then I'm afraid there's no such kind of Graph API to meet your requirement. For issue 2, `Group.ReadWrite.All` is added to the Azure AD application, but not all the users. You can still authorize specific users to use your app to manage the group. In other words, Azure AD application had the permission to manage group, so your application which uses the Azure AD app have the ability to manage group, but your application can also control who can use the application to manage group.....

Comment: `Wondering if Group Administrator role is working as intended` see the screenshot and I think it already explained what Groups Administrator can do.